# SQL Syntax Error When matching records to today

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull all bookings made today, however I'm coming across a syntax error for the final line.

```
SELECT
    booking.BookingID, booking.CustID, booking.CostID, booking.DateOut,
    customer.Fname, customer.Sname, costume.Description, costume.Size
FROM 
    booking
INNER JOIN 
    customer ON booking.CustID = customer.CustID
INNER JOIN 
    costume ON booking.CostID = costume.CostID
WHERE 
    booking.DateOut = Date();
```

Any help appreciated!

> Error Msg:
>              #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
>   LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: And please add the **exact** error message.

Comment: I guess `MySql` because of the [`Date` function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp).

Comment: Its MySQl, sorry for that

Comment: try `CURDATE()` instead, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    booking.BookingID, booking.CustID, booking.CostID, booking.DateOut,
    customer.Fname, customer.Sname, costume.Description, costume.Size
FROM 
    booking
INNER JOIN 
    customer ON booking.CustID = customer.CustID
INNER JOIN 
    costume ON booking.CostID = costume.CostID
WHERE 
    booking.DateOut = CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT booking.BookingID,
  booking.CustID,
  booking.CostID,
  booking.DateOut,
  customer.Fname,
  customer.Sname,
  costume.Description,
  costume.Size
FROM booking
INNER JOIN customer
ON (booking.CustID = customer.CustID)
INNER JOIN costume
ON (booking.CostID     = costume.CostID)
WHERE booking.DateOut = new_DATE(sysdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Date() function is used to Extract the date part of a date or datetime expression.
i.e. Date('12/02/2014 4.33 p.m') will give you '12/02/2014'.
So you have to supply a parameter to this function.

For your requirement you should use **CURDATE()** function .